# When will C++ Destructor for a global variable be called in NDK?

Tags: android, c++, global-variables, destructor, android-ndk

I recently encountered a strange issue while compiling an Android console program using NDK.

The class is declared like this:

```
class ClassP
{
public:
    ~ClassP()
    int number;
}
ClassP::~ClassP()
{
    printf("number=%d", number);
}
```

The main function is like this:

```
// global variable
ClassP p_instance;

int main()
{
    printf("test");
}
```

When the program is executed, it will output

```
test
Segmentation fault
```

After some basic debugging, I found out that when the destructor of ClassP is called, the address of its member variable number is 0. I think it is because p_instance is somehow freed before the destructor is called. But the behavior is not what I expected. Isn't the destructor of global variables called when the process is exiting and the system is trying to free all the objects?

Comment: This is C++, use `cout`, instead of `printf`, add `return 0; `in the `main`, initialize the `number` in the `default constructor` and try again. I'm not familiarized with NDK and android at all, but it's still C++

Comment: @KirilKirov There is nothing wrong with printf. The problem with cout is that it relies on objects which may be deconstructed before your object is.

Comment: Have you tried using GCC's `constructor` and `destructor` function attributes? If you can't get your class to work then maybe those will.

Answer (score 2):

Global variables are destructed when their process closes *or* when their module/dll is unloaded.

I'd assume your problem is with how you're registering your module with the NDK, it sounds like your code is either NOT being declared as a global variable like you're assuming (i.e. it's actually being called into a scope), or the module is being loaded, unloaded, then your function somehow called.

Take a look at some of the NDK samples in the SDK, and see if you're doing something very basic wrong; because your code as it stands is fine.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will check some samples of NDK. BTW, the code runs correctly on a PC using Linux (compiled by g++).

Answer (score 2):

```
class ClassP
{
    public:
        ~ClassP();
        int number;
};
ClassP::~ClassP()
{
    printf("number=%d", number);
}

// global variable
ClassP p_instance;

int main()
{
    printf("test");
}
```

Add the missing semi-colons

After class def and after class destructor and 
and the destructor runs fine

Ps output = testnumber=0

Comment: @Kiril Kirov - you can't initialize a var in the default constructor, that's why its the default constructor, if you create a constructor its then called a no-args constructor.

if you don't create a constructor then C++ creates a default con.. for you 

Just FYI